# How to destroy ol.Geolocation object in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers

I'm creating a geolocation object like this

```
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation( {
    projection: view.getProjection(),
    tracking: true,
    trackingOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: 30000,
        timeout: 10000
    }
} );
```

I want to delete it eventually. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried delete geolocation?

Comment: Delete the constructor won't change anything

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to stop it, use geolocation.setTracking(false)

Comment: I agree with that, except that the geolocation object is still in memory. Maybe I can try both, set tracking to false, and delete the object. Or reuse the same object if I want to track again

Comment: You have to remove all  reference to this object (remove it from the map) and tell js you don't need it (delete) then the garbage collector will do the job.